# Translating Nucleotides Triplets

Tags: r, string, split

I am trying to split a string of nucleotides in a way that allows me to find the outlier in the center of the nucleotide sequence, and turn it into a triplet by adding "n" to fill in the gaps.

I have tried splitting by number of characters, but the problem is that it happens from left to right, and I have been trying to find a way to do it right to left. So what I have done is find the length of the sequence, which in this one example is 52. Then, I take that length number and divide it by 3, to find the number of potential triplets that there will be. Then, I divide by 2 to know (obviously rounding) how many groups of 3 there will be roughly on each side of the outlier. Ideally, I want one more triplet on the left hand side than on the right hand side. The outlier would remain in the middle (either as one nucleotide, or two). For example:

```
nucleobases <- 'TGTGCCAGCAGTTTAAGGTAGATAGCGGGATTCCTACAATGAGCAGTTCTTC'
nucleolength <- nchar("TGTGCCAGCAGTTTAAGGTAGATAGCGGGATTCCTACAATGAGCAGTTCTTC")
num1 <- round(nucleolength/6)*3

firstsplit <- gsub("(.{27})", "\\1 ", nucleobases) #This works for the first half

secondsplit <- gsub("(.{24})", "\\1 ", firstsplit, rev) #This works, but not in the ideal way that it is supposed to.
```

I do not have any trouble translating the sequences into amino acids, which is my end goal. What I want is to add "n" in the places where it belongs in the sequence (on the outlier) so the ends of the sequences become the correct amino acids. This is ultimately what I would like:

```
#original sequence: TGTGCCAGCAGTTTAAGGTAGATAGCGGGATTCCTACAATGAGCAGTTCTTC
#split up in the correct places: TGTGCCAGCAGTTTAAGGTAGATAGCG G GATTCCTACAATGAGCAGTTCTTC
#"N" fills in the outlier: TGTGCCAGCAGTTTAAGGTAGATAGCG GNN GATTCCTACAATGAGCAGTTCTTC
#Gaps are then eliminated and sequence is translated: TGTGCCAGCAGTTTAAGGTAGATAGCGGNNGATTCCTACAATGAGCAGTTCTTC
#Translated sequence: CASSLR-IAXDSYNEQFF
```

If anyone has an idea of how to do this in an efficient way possible, it would be great to know! Also, something to keep in mind is that this is not the only sequence. There are other sequences with different lengths (47, 46, 35, etc.). To reiterate, the grouped sequence on the left should be longer than the right, with the outlier in the middle. Please keep in mind that the groups should be a multiple of 3 (since they are codons), all except for the outlier. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use `sub`, as well:

```
dna <- 'TGTGCCAGCAGTTTAAGGTAGATAGCGGGATTCCTACAATGAGCAGTTCTTC'

fillorf <- function(dna){
  nout <- nchar(dna) %% 3
  if(nout){
    nleft <- (nchar(dna) %/% 6 + 1) * 3 + nout
    dna <- sub(
      paste('(^.{', nleft, '})(.+$)', sep = ''),
      paste('\\1', substr('NN', 1, 3 - nout), '\\2', sep = ''),
      dna
    )
  }
  return(dna)
}

# > fillorf(dna)
# [1] "TGTGCCAGCAGTTTAAGGTAGATAGCGGNNGATTCCTACAATGAGCAGTTCTTC"
```

Comment: This works wonderfully! I was wondering what if I have a text file of the sequences and would want to create a dataframe of the original sequences in one column and the new sequences right next to it?

Comment: Glad it helped. It's not a problem to scale up mine or Andrew's approach. I'd put seqs into the list, to use function with lapply: `lapply(seq_list, fillorf)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple function to do this - perhaps something like the following...

```
nucleobases <- 'TGTGCCAGCAGTTTAAGGTAGATAGCGGGATTCCTACAATGAGCAGTTCTTC'

fill_outlier <- function(x){
  threes <- floor(nchar(x) / 3)                            #number of whole sets of three
  outlier <- 1 + 3 * ceiling(threes / 2)                   #number of threes to the left
  outlen <- nchar(x) %% 3                                  #length of outlier
  filled <- paste0(substr(x, 1, outlier-1),                #section before outlier
                   ifelse(outlen==0, "",                   #do nothing if multiple of 3
                      substr(paste0(substr(x, outlier, outlier + outlen - 1), #outlier
                                    "NN"),                 #pad it with Ns
                             1, 3)),                       #take first three characters
                   substr(x, outlier + outlen, nchar(x)))  #section after outlier
  return(filled)
}

fill_outlier(nucleobases)
[1] "TGTGCCAGCAGTTTAAGGTAGATAGCGGNNGATTCCTACAATGAGCAGTTCTTC"
```

This will be vectorised, so you can apply it directly to a vector of strings.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works for this sequence!! Would this work for a sequence where the outlier only needs one "N" to complete the triplet? And also if the sequence is a multiple of 3 (in length), then no "N"'s would be necessary.

Comment: I have added a line to ensure it works if there is no outlier, so it should be OK for all possible inputs.